# Error: this.j is null while using angular-google-maps Places service

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, angular-google-maps

I am using angular-google-maps version 2.3.2 with angular 1.5.0. I have installed all the map's dependencies and I am able to show the map, do search, markers, etc...

Ineed to programatically search for a place, so this is what I have:

for app config:

```
uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider.configure({
        libraries: 'places' // Required for SearchBox.
    });
```

view:

```
    <section>
    <div>
        <ui-gmap-google-map center='map.center' zoom='18' events="map.events" control="control">
            <ui-gmap-search-box template="map.template"
                                events="map.events"
                                options="map.marker.options">
            </ui-gmap-search-box>
            <ui-gmap-marker coords="map.marker.coords"
                            options="map.marker.options"
                            events="map.events"
                            idkey="map.marker.id">
            </ui-gmap-marker>
        </ui-gmap-google-map>
    </div>
</section>
```

logic:

```
uiGmapIsReady.promise()
            .then(function() {
                var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(scope.control);
                service.textSearch(textSearchRequest, callback);
            });
```

so I can create service itself but I am getting this error:

```
TypeError: this.j.getElementsByTagName is not a function
```

but it seems service was created:
[image]

and when I move debugger on from line you can see on pic I get:

```
    Error: this.j is null
_.t.textSearch/<@https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&libraries=places&language=en&callback=onGoogleMapsReady419:129:1328
_.L@https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&libraries=places&language=en&callback=onGoogleMapsReady419:50:49
_.t.textSearch@https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&libraries=places&language=en&callback=onGoogleMapsReady419:129:1291
createMapModel/<@http://localhost:9000/views/tools/map.srv.js:108:21
processQueue@http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:15552:28
scheduleProcessQueue/<@http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:15568:27
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$eval@http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:16820:16
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$digest@http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:16636:15
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$evalAsync/<@http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:16859:15
completeOutstandingRequest@http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:5804:7
Browser/self.defer/timeoutId<@http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:6081:7
```

I am using Firefox 44.0.2

Can you please tell me what is going wrong or what am I missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure where you are getting it from, but I don't think you have the right `google.maps` object. Try injecting the `uiGmapGoogleMapApi` service instead. So, your controller/service would look something like this:

```
uiGmapGoogleMapApi.then( function(maps) {
  var service = new maps.places.PlacesService(scope.control);
  service.textSearch(textSearchRequest, callback);
});
```

`uiGmapGoogleMapApi` is a promise that resolves to the `google.maps` object which you can use to create new services, etc.

EDIT:

To get both the `google.maps` object and your map instance try this. Make sure you inject `$q`, `uiGmapGoogleMapApi`, and `uiGmapIsReady` services:

```
$q.all([uiGmapGoogleMapApi, uiGmapIsReady.promise(1)]).then(function(responses) {
  var maps = responses[0];
  var instances = responses[1];
  // If you only have 1 map, this will be the object you want. Otherwise find the right one.
  var mapInstance = instances[0].map;
  var service = new maps.places.PlacesService(mapInstance);
  service.textSearch(textSearchRequest, callback);
});
```

Comment: although I think your comment does make sense, it is behaving the same as before...

Comment: Oh I just looked up the docs and you're supposed to pass your map instance to the PlacesService constructor. You do not get that from `scope.control`. That is most likely an empty object... I'll update my answer

Comment: well, if my map object would be empty it would fail on creating a places service. notice this line in my markup:
        <ui-gmap-google-map center='map.center' zoom='18' events="map.events" control="control">

where you can see that I am saving it to the scope's 'control' object

Comment: anyway, your solution working! I will suggest to the angular-google-maps dev team to update their documentation.
Thanks a lot!